Astro and react app not automatically showing new releases until user hard reload/clear cache
I have an app built-out and functioning well, built using React, Vite, and served by Astro. The build files are sent to an S3 bucket which is then deployed to a Cloudfront. To clarify, this is a microfrontend app, with the React child app being served statically by the Astro parent app.
Mainly with styling changes, users would have to hard reload/clear cache to see new releases. For example, I have implemented a sort of dynamic color-changing schema, that users can only see if they hard reload/clear cache. This implementation works fine in an incognito browser, which leads me to thinking it is a cache issue.
The expected behaviour is after build and push, users should be able to see the new changes on the site without having to clear cache/reload, which is not what is happening.
Has anyone run into this issue?
I have tried adding this to the index.html tag.
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />

Which on the "Network" tab on the console, I'd see the header for it includes "Cache-control: No cache". But it doesn't seem to fix my issue.
I have triple checked to make sure Cloudfront is clearing cache every time we push, and Cloudfront is.
I am considering cache-busting, but have heard that could come with a performance issue due to increased server load. If someone has a suggestion, or a library/tech (I have heard may be Webpack or a Vite package?) you have tried that worked for you, I would love to hear it.

Definitely sounds like Cloudfront isn't configured like you'd expect, pretty sure the Cloudfront HTTP headers take precedence over the meta tags so those are useless. Check the network tab for the HTML document as well to see what content and headers CF returns.
